# TYPO3 : SimplePoll : show the last

Tags: typo3

currently I'm using `simplepoll.uid` to show a Poll on the Frontend :

```
lib.poll = USER
lib.poll {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = Simplepoll
    pluginName = Polllisting
    vendorName = Pixelink
    settings =< plugin.tx_simplepoll.settings
    settings {
        simplepoll.uid = 13 // this is the ID of the Poll to show
    }
    persistence =< plugin.tx_news.persistence
    view =< plugin.tx_news.view 
}
```

is there a way to show automatically the last poll added to the storagePid instead of `simplepoll.uid` ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that my solution does not work as there might be no `stdWrap` support in the extension. Then you should ask the extension author to build in the wrapping (or support him with a pull request).

Requesting the uid from the last created poll should be possible with an SQL query which selects the highest uid.

An SQL query can be done in typoscript with the `CONTENT` object:

```
lib.poll {
   settings {
      simplepoll.uid.cObject = CONTENT
      simplepoll.uid.cObject {
         table = tx_poll... // get the exact page name
         select {
            selectFields = uid
            pidInList = ??? // insert storage page of your polls
            orderBy = uid DESC
            max = 1            
         }
         renderObj = TEXT
         renderObj. field = uid
      }
   }
}
```

You need no `WHERE` clause to select no deleted and hidden records as these where inserted automatically.

Be aware to create polls in hidden mode otherwise an incomplete poll could be selected.

---

testing with

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.poll.settings.simplepoll.uid.cObject" />
```

or

```
page.1 < lib.poll.settings.simplepoll.uid.cObject
page.1.wrap = <h1>poll = [|]</h1>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work out., I get the error : `pollNotFound`

Comment: test it with a viewhelper or some typoscript whether the uid is calculated correct