# Giving no-admin users access to Template module

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I'm setup a TYPO3 website and I need to give a user group the permission to view and edit to the `Template` module.

[image]

On the TYPO3 documentation I found this information :

> If you cannot see the Template module, it may be that you are not
>   logged in as an administrator. Please  change user and make sure you
>   use one with administrator rights.

There is no a work-around to give backend users access to the Template
module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the "Web -> Template" module accessible to non-administrators

> typo3\sysext\frontend\Configuration\TCA\sys_template.php

Change line 16:

```
'adminOnly' => true,
```

to

```
'adminOnly' => false,
```

Now, you can Edit Backend usergroup and check the option `Template [sys_template]` on `Tables (listing)` and `Tables (modify)`

Answer (score 0):

No possibility except you xclass core methods.

Maybe there is another solution to your problem.
Please state why an editor should have access to the template module.

Comment: I'm using SimplePoll extension and editor need to change the `ID` variable on TS `simplepoll.uid = x` each time there's a new poll. If I find a way to automatically add the last poll, my problem will be solved.

Comment: that should be possible. With the `CONTENT` object you can do an SQL query. You might need something like: `SELECT uid FROM tx_poll... WHERE deleted = 0 and hidden = 0 ORDER uid DESC LIMIT 1` (post another question if you need help)

Comment: Thanks, I've already asked my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157745/typo3-simplepoll-show-the-last, but I didn't get any answers.

Comment: sorry, have not seen it at as I was in vacation. ;)